# What are the maps of these closed sets in $\mathbb R^3 \mapsto \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

What is the map of an elipsoid(closed) if $H(x,y,z)=x+y+z$

This is kind of an tricky question, because I am not sure precisely what the answer is. I think when it says closed elipsoid it can be either one of these two, probably being the first:

$$1.\ \ \  \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=r^2 \\ 2. \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\leq r^2 $$

Intuition (and some knowledge) is telling me that the image is closed, compact, connected, seeing as the function is continuous. But I have no idea on quantifying, or precisely defining the answer.

And the same question except the map of a closed ball $\overline{B^3(0,1)}$ is asked and the function being: $$f(x,y,z)=(\frac{x}{3},\frac{y}{2}-1,\frac{z}{9}+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Either kind of ellipsoid is closed and path-wise connected in $\Bbb R^3$. $H$ is a continuous function so the image of the ellipsoid under the map is also closed and path-wise connected in $\Bbb R$. The values of $|x|$, $|y|$, and $|z|$ for points in either ellipsoid are bounded by $a^2r^2$, $b^2r^2$, and $c^2r^2$ respectively, so by the triangle inequality the values of $H$ are also bounded:

$$|x+y+z|\le |x|+|y|+|z|\le a^2r^2+b^2r^2+c^2r^2$$

So the image under $H$ is non-empty, closed, bounded, and path-wise connected in $\Bbb R$. That means the image is a closed interval.

You could even use Lagrange multipliers or a parametrization of the ellipsoid to find out exactly which closed interval, if needed.

All that also applies to the closed ball and the function $f$. The main difference is that the closed interval in that case is not necessarily symmetric with the point zero, due to the lack of symmetry in $f$.